# c++ == operator double

Tags: c++, floating-point, equality

I know it is incorrect to compare double (equality) and the best is to use an epsilon factor as described into the Knuth book (Art of programming). Nevertheless, I am working on a legacy code (C++), where there are a lot of devision like:

```
// b,c double from previous computation
if( b == 50.0) 
    b += 0.001;
double a = c/(b - 50.0);
```

Do we perform the conditional statement (b == 50) on the "bit representation" (mantissa-exponenent) or the decimal one ?  I do not find this information on my C++ book. If it is the decimal, I think I can trough away the conditional statement.

Comment: floating point (here double)

Comment: 50 is exactly representable in double. Was b initialized with a literal, or the result of a chain of calculations with exact results?

Comment: @user3956566 I do not see what the “great answer” there does for the question “Do we perform the conditional statement (b == 50) on the "bit representation" (mantissa-exponenent) or the decimal one ?” being asked.

Comment: I know this it comes from knuth, the question is as this comparison exists in the legacy code since 30 years, I consider it as outdated, should it be  better to remove it ? I still do not know if during the execution the conditional statement will become true, and if yes does it become true due to the good math reason

Comment: @Timocafé “I still do not know if during the execution the conditional statement will become true” Yes, some floating-point values for `b` can make the condition `b == 50.0` true. You shouldn't be touching this code if you have to ask this question, not that it may not have problems, but because it would require more familiarity with the intent of the code and with floating-point than you have to make the code better.

Comment: I have to refactor it, this question of branching is "really important", I have thousands of this branching, ok it can appends, presently I will prefer a NAN than add an epsilon and change deeply the results

Comment: This think performed ODE (ordinary differential equation), I fear the branching can be true due to rounding effect (as explain in the next post), I will introduce a corrector factor, that change the final result. Moreover I am using a SIMD framework, and branching are just SIMD unfriendly. From the answer of @PascalCuoq I prefer remove this branching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `==` operator is applied to the run-time representation of the floating-point value, ideally with exactly the exponent and significand numbers of bits implied by the type, but unfortunately, sometimes in a wider format, as allowed by the standard.

In `b == 50.0`, the decimal representation 50.0 is converted to such a floating-point representation at compile-time once and for all. That value is then used (or the program behaves as if it was used) each time this expression `50.0` is involved. In the case of `50.0`, it does not make a difference because the number 50 can be represented exactly as a binary floating-point value.

As an example, `b == 50.0000000000000000000001` is likely to behave **exactly** as `b == 50.0` because `50.0000000000000000000001` represents the same floating-point value as `50.0`.

Answer (score 3):

For the specific piece of code, the use of exact comparison is correct:

```
// b,c double from previous computation
if( b == 50.0) 
    b += 0.001;
double a = c/(b - 50.0);
```

The purpose seems to be to ensure that the division will not be a division by zero. The code may have been written to be compatible with systems in which division by 0 causes failure, rather than infinity. Subtracting 50 from any double that is not exactly 50 will have a non-zero result, so the 0.001 fudge factor only needs to be added in the case of exact equality.